# c# Databindings Null-Value Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

We have some issues with Databindings, when it comes down to `null`-values.

For example, the databinding to a checkbox looks like this:

```
public void DataBindLambda<T>(IDBEntity entity, Expression<Func<T>> propertyLambda)
  {
      this.DataBindings.Add("Checked", entity, CodeUtils.GetPropertyName(propertyLambda), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
  }
```

Now, if the field of the entity is nullable (in the database), the binding fails with `System.FormatException: 'Value '' cannot be converted to type 'Boolean'.'`

this so far is understandable, to eliminiate that error, we can handle the null-value as false:

```
public void DataBindLambda<T>(IDBEntity entity, Expression<Func<T>> propertyLambda)
  {
     this.DataBindings.Add("Checked", entity, CodeUtils.GetPropertyName(propertyLambda), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, false);
  }
```

This works for 95% of checkboxes, where we savely can handle `null` as `false` - however now we have an edge case, where this does not work:

The Database Value is reflecting the state of an approval to give:

- `null` not yet decided, approver has to approve
- `false` it is NOT approved
- `true` it is approved.

In this case, the logic to handle `null` as `false` obvisously is leading to undesired results.

It can be solved in other ways, but since the null value is an recurring issue with databindings (date, numerics, boolean) I wonder how this would be generally solved?

Is there a way, to apply the `null`-substitution just one way?
i.e. saying "IF the database value is null, then consider it false. IF false is selected, then apply false to the data model (not `DB_NULL`)

Comment: Just a thought is that this seems a little x-y in that there are three _actual_ states that might be better visualized as a ComboBox bound to `enum Approval { Pending, Approved, Denied }` and `public property Approval Approval { get; set; }`. In other words using a `bool` is a round peg in a square hole to begin with IMO (that is if changing the bound class is even an option here).

Comment: @IVSoftware Many better solutions possible, yes. - But if business says "We want a checkbox!" - they'll get a checkbox :P

Answer (score 2):

If the data is nullable then set the `ThreeState` property of the control to `true` and bind to the `CheckState` property instead of `Checked`. In that case, you'll have to do the conversion between the nullable `bool` data in the `DataTable` and the `CheckState` values in the control. To do that, you need to set `FormattingEnabled` to `true` on the binding (which you are) and then handle the `Format` and `Parse` events. `Format` is raised when passing data from data source to control:

```cs
if (e.Value == DBNull.Value)
{
    e.Value = CheckState.Indeterminate;
}
else
{
    e.Value = (bool)e.Value ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked;
}
```

`Parse` is raised when passing data from control to data source:

```cs
switch ((CheckState)e.Value)
{
    case CheckState.Checked:
        e.Value = true;
        break;
    case CheckState.Unchecked:
        e.Value = false;
        break;
    case CheckState.Indeterminate:
        e.Value = DBNull.Value;
        break;
}
```

Comment: thx for the hint about `Parse` and `Format` events - they seem pretty useful to handle edge-cases as well. Yes, We did it with a three state checkbox, where we didn't even need to override the methods , cause we just said "CheckState.Indeterminate is null-value" but for `Date-Pickers` and `Numeric-Up-Downs` the methods will be handy, cause on a numeric-up-down "0=null" (or any other possible non-null-value) can yield undesired results. So, with these methods it's actually easy to track a dedicated `null-flag` and render the not-nullable-control different.